# QProgressBar connect progress between classes - "no matching function for call"

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals, qprogressbar, qt-slot

I have some troubles in correct set of Signal and Slots between one class in which I do some calculations and the other one which contain GUI with my progress bar. I have very small experience with qt so I don't feel well how the signal/slots works. I tried few manuals and tutorials but I still don't know how to set it.

Let's call the progress bar class `mainwindow`

`mainwindow.h`

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow*ui;
};

#endif // LOADING_H
```

`mainwindow.cpp`

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "calc.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->progressBar->setValue(0);
    calc sender;
    connect(&sender, SIGNAL( inprogress(int) ), ui->progressBar, SLOT( setValue(int) ) );
}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    calc clc;
    clc.doData();
}
```

Signal is emitted from calculation class, call it short `calc`

`calc.h`

```
#ifndef CALC_H
#define CALC_H

#include <QObject>

class calc : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    calc(QObject *parent=0);
    void doData();
    void printResults(int t);
signals:
    void inprogress(int progr);

};

#endif // CALC_H
```

`calc.cpp`

```
#include "calc.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

int t = 0;
int t_end = 100;
int progr = 0;

void calc::printResults(int t)
{
    progr = t;
    emit inprogress(progr);
    QCoreApplication::processEvents(); //Prevent GUI freeze.
}

void calc::doData()
{
    for ( int i = 1; i <= t_end; i++ )
    {
        t++;
        printResults(t);
        qDebug()<<t;
    }
}

calc::calc(QObject *parent)
{

}
```

> **Archiev part (code above edited)**
>   The compilation ends with this error:
>   no matching function for call to 'loading::connect(calc*, const char*,
>   QProgressBar*&, const char*)
>   Do I use signals in correct way, or I misunderstand this concept? What's the >correct way to update value of progress bar during this calculations?

**EDIT:** Code edited to be more clear, now it show current question - signal works but has no effect on qprogressbar.

**EDIT2:** Now works - function has to be call `sender->doData()`. Additionally correct assignment is `sender = new calc(this)` (with `calc *sender` added to private section of mainwidnow.h). Thanks  you, everyone, for help, especially @eyllanesc for point correct way!

Comment: calc must be QObject-based. sod right way is
 class calc : public QObject
{
Q_Object
public:
    calc(QObject *prnt) : QObject(prtn) {....}
.....
And you create your calc but you didn't strore it. So when you go out of constructor scope your calc exemplar will be destroyed

Comment: At what time do you call the doData function?

Comment: it's called when user push buton placed under progress bar, look: `void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the classes that inherit from `QObject` can have signals, in addition they must have the Macro `Q_OBJECT`, since this through the MOC creates all the necessary metaclass for the connection between signals and slots. In your case:

***.h**

```
class calc: public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
    public:
        calc(QObject *parent=0);
        void signalProgress();
    signals:
        void inprogress();

};
```

***.cpp**

```
[...]

calc::calc(QObject *parent): QObject(parent)
{

}
```

Also create a calc instance through a pointer as the garbage collector will delete that data after you use the constructor.

***.h**

```
private:
    Ui::loading *ui;
    calc *sender;
```

***.cpp**

```
loading::loading(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::loading)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->progressBar->setValue(0);
    sender = new calc(this);
    connect(sender, SIGNAL( inprogress(int) ), ui->progressBar, SLOT( setValue(int) ) );
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153687/discussion-on-answer-by-eyllanesc-qprogressbar-connect-progress-between-classes). If you have a follow-up question or want to share more code, edit the question. If there is something that needs to be clarified about this answer, edit it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, question edited with full code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  QObject-based class in order to establish a connection

In your calc header file, you will have to inherit from QObject and then to add the [Q_OBJECT](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT) macro

calc.h

```
class calc : pubilc QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
    calc();
    void signalProgress();
signals:
    void inprogress(int progr);

};
```

There's tons of examples and documentation using Qt signals & slots you can start reading [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html)

P.S.

[QProgressBar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qprogressbar.html) is also Object-based class so the same logic is already implemented here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but as I said in previous answer (which was delated, I don't know why) after this changes it compiles, but `emit` has no effect on progress bar. It always stay at default value. I did some test in different configurations and it seems that it works only if executed in specific way. Look at this exampel from previouse discusion:
https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/b2e2d63ea8bfe1b4e6e580f9ba0eddbc
But if you move `emit` from `connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [this]{
 signalProgress();progr++;qDebug()<<progr;});` to for exampe other function it stop works.

Comment: I edited my code to be more specific, now it's more clear in which way I need to call `emit`.